# Hair: stand up,stick up (are these interchangeable)

Tags: word-usage

Are   "stand"   and    "stick up" interchangeable ?

Like:

> Static charge makes our hair **stand up/stand on end.**
>
> Static charge makes our hair **stick up.**

And here:

> He always gels down his hair and that's why not even a single hair strand is **standing up/sticking up**. (**And is it natural to mention "a single hair strand", because I want to emphasize more dramatically.**)
>
> My hair is always **sticking up/standing up**.

I guess "stand" is used with static charge and "stick up is used otherwise". Am I right? What do you think?

Comment: stick up and stand have zero to do with electricity. "a strand of hair sticks up".

Comment: @Lambie what will you be more likely to use with "static electricity",  "stick up" Or "stand up/on end"?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish It's completely subjective. Both are fine. In this context, they mean the same thing.

Comment: @JasonBassford You don't need an @ under the question. :)  Anyway, I would not say: I had a strand of hair standing up. And stand "on end" is not right here.